# Spring Scanner bean

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to configure a Scanner bean in Spring, I figure it would be something close to:

```
<bean id="input" class="java.util.Scanner">
    <constructor-arg type="InputStream"><value>java.lang.System.in</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do this? If not, could you please supply a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, what you want to achive from this,

You can create a InputStream spring bean,

```
<bean id="stream" class="java.io.InputStream">

<bean id="input" class="java.util.Scanner">
        <constructor-arg index="0"><ref bean="stream"/></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: java.io.InputStream is an abstract class. how you instantiate from it?